# Porting Visual Basic staements to Perl Win32::OLE ones

Tags: perl, vba, excel, win32ole

I read all the standard Win32::OLE texts such as [Jan Dubois' classic](http://search.cpan.org/~gsar/libwin32-0.191/OLE/lib/Win32/OLE/TPJ.pod) and of course the [official package doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aOLE), Microsoft's terse article and many others.

What I miss are rules to convert a captured VBA Excel macro statement into a Perl Win32::OLE one.

Say I have a captured VBA macro:

```
Sub cntrl_arrow_down()
     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
End Sub
```

Assuming I already obtained an application (Excel) object, a "book" object, a "sheet" object and activated the sheet. Further, I selected a cell and I am looking to find the extent down of the column in which the cell is. I would like to get a 'Range' object that I can next read the range into a 2D Perl array.

Please, I need the rules, not just the answer to this particular line.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using Perl, why do you have to use Win32::OLE, and not one of the Excel modules?  Of course, if you're really after how to run VBA macros, that's one thing.  But if you just need to interface with Excel file, there are modules for doing that in Perl (without OLE).

Comment: A good question! Let me look it over.

Comment: Thank you jimtut! A long time ago I used Perl to manipulate Excel spreadsheets, both reading and writing, and at that time I was convinced that the Win32::OLE must be the best, being developed by those who developed OLE, isn't it? I recently needed to do it again so I never stopped to reconsider. jimtut made me do so, and I discovered that all these xxx::Excel::yyy modules lurking on CPAN are a lot easier to use and more accessible to additions and enhancements. In my case it was Excel::Table and its descendants.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I still don't know the answer to my original question *(and that a good answer to it is still going to be useful to many)*, but I found an alternative set of tools, see jimtut comments and my response above.

Answer (score 0):

Copying my original comment here into a full Answer, since it seemed to help the op (and maybe it will be Accepted as the Answer):

If you're using Perl, why do you have to use Win32::OLE, and not one of the Excel modules? Of course, if you're really after how to run VBA macros, that's one thing. But if you just need to interface with Excel file, there are modules for doing that in Perl (without OLE).